# External HDD - filenames not showing

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I've an external HDD with NTFS. I was playing an avi file on OSX 10.6.4 using it. After I closed the avi file, I found out that the folder in which the file was stored was neither accessible through "cd". Neither was any other file in the folder containing that avi file. In addition, half of the directories and/or files in the parent folder of the folder containing the avi file were not listed in finder, nor listed when I typed "ls". Some of them could still be accessed via "cd" or "open" to open the file but not all.

Basically for some reason a lot of my content is not showing up using "ls" or Finder though some of it can still be accessed by typing in the exact path in the terminal (not all though).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Edit: I should add that I tried using the Repair Disk option in Disk Utility but that is greyed out. 
Edit2: The partition is NTFS, not HFS+.

Comment: Did you verify/repair your disk using Disk Utility?

Comment: Yes. Both options are greyed out.

Comment: Since it's NTFS, how do you access it? The read-only access, or MacFUSE with NTFS-3G, or something else? Do the files show up when accessed from a Windows system?

Comment: Might [this](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#locale3) be relevant?

Comment: It's read-only access. Haven't tested on a Windows system but will soon. I'll try setting up NTFS-3G with MacFuse I guess and see how that goes.

Comment: I suggest you disconnect and connect to a Windows system **first**. Run Checkdisk and whatever else there is.

Comment: Not showing up with ls in terminal? Are you sure you are in the right directory?
Have you gone to FINDER then Preferences, then look under general and sidebar for options to show discs?